# Phonegap - swipe right Facebook style navigation / layout

Tags: jquery, ios, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know if its possible to replicate the 'swipe right for notification menu' Facebook style functionality using Phonegap for IOS?

It will be a standard Phonegap app other than the addition of right swipe at any point which will always display slide in the notification menu.  No idea how to set this up though...

Any suggestions?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064816/jquery-mobile-slide-in-menu-solution/13064919#13064919

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try using [App UI](http://triceam.github.com/app-UI/) it provides the functionality you need. If you check the video, you will see the 'Sliding View' which is essentially the same as the iOS Facebook menu.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but from a standard phonegap project, that functionality would be difficult to implement as phonegap uses a webview and a bunch of javascript libraries to link into the devices' features.

What you can do if you are brave enough is to attach a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the webview that gets called on the application delegate. When it detects this, you need to animate the webview out the way to show another view (the tableview that facebook uses) that was behind it.

In all honesty, you are almost better off writing it native, rather than overwriting what phonegap gives you.

Answer (score 0):

The beta version of jQuery Mobile, which works with Phonegap, has the panel feature built into it.
Check it out here:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/

But yeah check out this similar thread, as mentioned above: 
[Jquery-mobile slide in menu solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064816/jquery-mobile-slide-in-menu-solution/13064919#13064919)

That one custom implemented it, using an older version of jQuery mobile.